# Map entities to database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mapping

I've made a quite big domain model with entity framework. I wanted to know if it is possible to map it so i create automaticly the tables in the database wanted?

I've looked up edmgen.exe but still couldn't find the right command.

thank's for helping!

Edit1: I know the tool LightSpeed from Mindscape ofer this features that's why i think that entity framework does the same.

Edit2 : Non one likes me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently this is not available but i thing this feature will be shipped with vs2010

Answer (score 2):

According to this [blog entry](http://blog.nakedobjects.net/?p=58), it's currently (v1) not possible to create the database from an entity model.

About half way down, under the heading of "2. Process and tooling issues", you'll find:

> - It is not currently possible to create the database schema
>     automatically from the Entity Model.
>     This is simply extraordinary - as it
>     seems to easy to do!

Let's hope for EF v2 (in .NET 4.0 / VS2010).

Marc

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the answer is "no."  The Entity Framework isn't necessarily meant to map 1-1 to the database, it's actually supposed to be a business object representation of how you want to use data stored in the database.  Therefore it would be very, very difficult to write something that created a database from your Entity Model since you can't expect things to be mapped back to the database on a 1-1 level.